# Fill a ListView with LINQ SPROC result

Tags: c#, linq, listview, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I'm developing a desktop app with C#. I'm using LINQ to recovering data from my database with stored procedures. I execute the next query:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_SelectRecords] 
@idproduct nchar(10) 
as 
select Id_Product,Description,Sell_Price from Tbl_Products 
where Id_Product=@idproduct
```

This query recieve parameter from my application and return me one record which I want to display on ListView.

```
linqDataContext _linq = new linq_DataContext();
private void txtParam1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            var res = _linq.sp_SelectRecords(txtParam1.Text);
            //Here I want to add result of SPROC to ListView
            listView1.Items.Add(res);//I though that this could work like 'DataGridView.DataSource=res'
            //But DataGridView display records of query at moment
            //And I want add records every time that executes a query
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us what you did, if you dont know check the following link for a tutorial  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4012/C-List-View-v1-3

Comment: I edit my post with a part of code where I execute the SPROC

Comment: are you getting any error or what ??

Comment: Yes! In the line "listView1.Items.Add(res)", I get next error: Cannot convert from 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<MySolution.sp_SelectRecordsResult>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answer 'alancnet'! But after of give it spins on my head, I try this and I got it!

```
var res = _linq.sp_SelectRecords(txtParam1.Text);
            foreach (var order in res)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new[] { order.Cod_Prod, order.Description, order.Price.ToString() });
                ListView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
```

Comment: That will work :) Thought I'd give you an elegant LINQ answer.

Comment: Anyway... thanks for offering your help, alancenet! ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you add an item to a `ListView`, it must either be a string, or a `ListViewItem`. If you add a `ListViewItem`, you can actually store a reference to an object with it:

```
myListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(MyObject.Text)
{
    Tag = MyObject
});
```

Using this method, you can add your single record to the `ListView` as I have done above, or add an entire series of records to it like this:

```
myListView.Items.AddRange(
    (
        items.Select(
            item => new ListViewItem(item.Text) 
            { 
                Tag = item 
            }
        )
    ).ToArray()
);
```

When you want to access the selected object, you can retrieve a reference to it like this:

```
myListView.SelectedItems[0].Tag
```